# CookieException with CookieContainer: The 'Path' part of the cookie is invalid

Tags: c#, cookies, windows-phone-8

I am trying to set the path of a cookie but I am always recieving the error:

`CookieException: The 'Path'='/applogin'` part of the cookie is invalid.

the code looks like this:

```
Cookie newCookie = new Cookie("JSESSIONID", session.SessionId, "/applogin", "domain.com");
newCookie.Secure = true;
webRequest.CookieContainer.Add(new Uri(@"https://domain.com"), newCookie);
```

the exception is then throwen on the last line... can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 12):

In your case you have two urls: one is a `https://domain.com` and second one is a `https://domain.com/applogin`. Let's assume that CookieContainer contains your cookie for path /applogin. This means that if you will try to retrieve list of cookies for url `https://domain.com/applogin` - you will get one cookie. If you will try to retrieve cookies for url `https://domain.com` - you will get 0 cookies.

Now let's look on your sample. You have a cookie for `https://domain.com/applogin` and you are trying to add it to CookieContrainer for url `https://domain.com`. CookieContainer verifies that this cookie cannot be used for specific url, because it was issues for different url. In your case you need to change line where you add cookie:

```
webRequest.CookieContainer.Add(new Uri(@"https://domain.com/applogin"), newCookie);
```

Or I guess you want to use this cookie for whole domain.com - then you need to change how you create it to

```
Cookie newCookie = new Cookie("JSESSIONID", session.SessionId, "/", "domain.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

In some browsers, the path is case sensitive. Make sure all references to "/applogin" match the case exactly.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: The URL path is *always* case sensitive.

Comment: Windows web servers are case insensitive while Linux/Unix are case sensitive. This is because windows' file system is case insensitive while Linux/Unix is case sensitive. However, when performing a cookie request the browser never sends the cookie path to the server, it compares it with what the server returns from the name/value pairs. I believe all browsers are case sensitive about this, but I am not certain.

Comment: URL paths are case insensitive, no matter how a web server decides to map URL paths to file system paths.

Answer (score -1):

Cookie name:
-cant be null or empty
-cant be start and end with ' '
-cant be include service symbols, such as \r, '\n', '\t', '=', ';',','
-cant be start with '$'[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYaK4.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fUA1.png)